VS Code input needs to be done multiple times
I use a loop to determine if input is correct and if wrong to ask again till input is valid the programm does run but I have to input the number multiple times. If I do run the code on another machine, it runs smothly with just the first input.
Here's an example but it is the same, no matter what loop I choose.
  while (input != 1 || getchar() != '\n') {
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
        
        input = scanf ("%d", &number);
        if (input != 1 || getchar() != '\n') {
            printf ("Try again!\n");
        }
    }

Changed the structure of the code and changed the loop conditions and the loop-body, but still multiple times input or one run.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char c;
int input = 0, loopvariable = 1, number, secondtolastfibo = 1, lastbuttwofibo = 1;
long lastfibo;


printf ("Fibonacci-Numbers\n"
        "How many Fibonacci do you want? ");

while (input != 1 || getchar() != '\n') {
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
    
    input = scanf ("%d", &number);
    if (input != 1 || getchar() != '\n') {
    printf ("Try a positive number!\n");
    }
}

secondtolastfibo = 1;
lastbuttwofibo = 1;
printf ("%d. \t%d\n", loopvariable, secondtolastfibo);
loopvariable++;
printf ("%d. \t%d\n", loopvariable, secondtolastfibo);
while (loopvariable < number) {
    
    fflush(stdin);
    loopvariable++;
    lastfibo = secondtolastfibo + lastbuttwofibo;
    lastbuttwofibo = secondtolastfibo;
    secondtolastfibo = lastfibo;

    printf ("%d. \t%ld\n", loopvariable, lastfibo);
    
    if (loopvariable % 10 == 0) {
        printf ("Continue with Return.......");
        getchar();
    }
}


return 0;

}
In- and Output:
Fibonacci-Numbers
How many Fibonacci do you want? 23\n
23\n


 1



 1



 2



...
Changed the loop conditions: got rid of "while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)" or changed the loop condition to (input !=1) or put input = scanf(...) outside the loop and the loop condition to (input !=1) but it didn't work and still had to input multiple times for it to start.

My recommendation is that you use fgets to read a whole line, and then use e.g. sscanf or strtol to convert the input to a number with validation. That way your code will become much simpler, and you don't need two loops or all those getchar calls (which are the likely culprits).

Please [edit] your question and create [mcve]. It's impossible to know for sure what is the problem, when we cannot run the same code as you do.

Welcome to SO. This statement: "Changed the structure of the code and changed the loop conditions and the loop-body, is basically identical to "I did some random stuff that I don't tell you". Unless you tell us what changes you made, this sentence is not of any use for any reader.

You're consuming and discarding some of the input with getchar calls. You can just use scanf here.

@interjay I need to make sure that only integers are in input and not for example 34erfd, that's why getchar(). I could use char as well but it doesn't solve the problem.

But the getchar gets rid of both integers and non-integers.

The scanset %1[\n] will scan for one character that must be a newline. The scan will append a zero to the output so char newline[2] is the minimum required. %*[^\n] will scan and discard everything that is not a newline.
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    char newline[2] = "";
    int input = 2, loopvariable = 1, number = 0, secondtolastfibo = 1, lastbuttwofibo = 1;
    long lastfibo = 0;


    printf ("Fibonacci-Numbers\n"
    "How many Fibonacci do you want? ");

    do {
        if ( input != 2) {
            scanf ( "%*[^\n]"); // scan and discard everything not a newline
            printf ( "\tTry again\n");
        }
        input = scanf ("%d%1[\n]", &number, newline); // scan for integer and a newline
        if (input == EOF) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "EOF\n");
            return 1;
        }
    } while (input != 2);

    secondtolastfibo = 1;
    lastbuttwofibo = 1;
    printf ("%d. \t%d\n", loopvariable, secondtolastfibo);
    loopvariable++;
    printf ("%d. \t%d\n", loopvariable, secondtolastfibo);
    while (loopvariable < number) {

        loopvariable++;
        lastfibo = secondtolastfibo + lastbuttwofibo;
        lastbuttwofibo = secondtolastfibo;
        secondtolastfibo = lastfibo;

        printf ("%d. \t%ld\n", loopvariable, lastfibo);

        if (loopvariable % 10 == 0) {
            do {
                printf ("Continue with Return.......");
                scanf ( "%*[^\n]"); // scan and discard everything not a newline
                input = scanf ( "%1[\n]", newline); // scan for one character that muse be a newline
                if (input == EOF) {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "EOF\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            } while (input != 1);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}


thanks for the help. But do you know what was wrong with my code that I needed to do the input multiple times?
